# Scala - Pattern Matching and For loop issue

Tags: scala, for-loop, pattern-matching

I'm trying to solve the problem 12 of [S-99: Ninety-Nine Scala Problems](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/)

> Given a run-length code list generated as specified in problem P10,
>   construct its uncompressed version. Example:

```
scala> decode(List((4, 'a), (1, 'b), (2, 'c), (2, 'a), (1, 'd), (4, 'e)))
res0: List[Symbol] = List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a, 'b, 'c, 'c, 'a, 'a, 'd, 'e, 'e, 'e, 'e)
```

I was trying to pattern match the element in the list and then use a for loop to concatenate the char but I've got the following compilation error on line 5 :

```
type mismatch;  found   : scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[List[A]]  required: List[A]
```

---

```
1 def decode[A](xs: List[(Int, A)]) : List[A] = xs match {
2     case Nil => Nil
3     case x :: xs => {
4                    for {
5                       i <- 1 to x._1
6                    }  yield (x._2) :: decode(xs)
7                   }
8 }
```

Sorry but I begin Scala. Could someone explain why this is happening and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are quite close - just a couple of problems. Here is a fixed version I came up with:

```
def decode[A](xs: List[(Int, A)]) : List[A] = xs match {
   case Nil => Nil
   case x :: xs => (for {
                       i <- 1 to x._1
                    } yield (x._2)).toList ::: decode(xs)
}
```

The first - and probably most important - thing is the extra parentheses around the for-yield. Without this, you are trying to yield `(x._2) :: decode(xs)`, rather than just `(x._2)` (to make up for that, the `{}` around the whole case can be omitted).

Next, the for-yield results in an IndexedSeq rather than a List, so I forced a conversion to List (you could handle this in various ways, this was merely the most expedient).

Finally, concatenating to the List resulting from `decode(xs)` requires the `:::` operator (you can also use `++`) rather than `::` (which prepends a single entry, not a sub-list).

Comment: [yet another version](https://gist.github.com/lazyval/bf0208414becf2e4e1ec) (not posting inline since github does pretty bad things with code formatting in comments)

Answer (score 4):

The main issue is the operator you use for concatenating lists - `::` is used only to prepend a single element to a list, so in your code you are trying to prepend the result of the yield (which is itself a sequence) to a `List[A]` and get type incompatibility as a result. Here is a modified version that will work - it uses operator `++:` which can be used to join two sequences together. I also moved the `yield` to a separate statement, otherwise you would need parentheses around the yield so that `++:` works on the complete result of the `yield` and not on each element (which would again not compile due to types not matching).

```
def decode[A](xs: List[(Int, A)]) : List[A] = xs match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case x :: xs => {
    val repeatedElems = for {
      i <- 1 to x._1
    }  yield (x._2)
    repeatedElems ++: decode(xs)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer too ! =) I can only accept one answer so I'll upvote yours instead =)

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are perfectly fine but I think generating the decoded lists with `List.fill`  requires less syntax and is easier to understand compared to the `for-yield` expression.

```
def decode[A](xs: List[(Int, A)]) : List[A] = xs match {
   case Nil => Nil
   case x :: xs => List.fill(x._1)(x._2) ::: decode(xs)
}
```

Output:

```
scala> decode(List((4, 'a), (1, 'b), (2, 'c), (2, 'a), (1, 'd), (4, 'e)))
res0: List[Symbol] = List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a, 'b, 'c, 'c, 'a, 'a, 'd, 'e, 'e, 'e, 'e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly modified version of Brian's answer. Decomposing the tuple makes the code even more readable:

```
def decode[A](xs: List[(Int, A)]) : List[A] = xs match {
   case Nil => Nil
   case (count, letter) :: xs => List.fill(count)(letter) ::: decode(xs)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is using map:

```
def decode[A](l: List[(Int, A)]): List[A] = {
  val l1: List[List[A]] = l map { e =>
    List.fill(e._1)(e._2)
  }
  l1.flatten
}
```

Comment: flatMap will be a lot more readable (no intermediate variable at all)